# Is there a way in git to get changes that were lost in a merge

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, gitlab

Background : I am working on a project with a coworker, it is a massive project (to us) that we've been working on for the last 3 years. There are a ton of branches for features, bug fixes, builds etc. Pretty normal project I think. We were both working on new features in different branches, finished and merged those changes into the dev branch.

Fast forward a couple of days and we are testing the new application build, we realize that during the merges to dev I accidentally stomped on about 10 lines of code that he had added to a db migration.

Question : Is there a way in git to go back and grab those 10 lines of code and bring them back?

I know I could just go back to the commit, copy the code and paste it where it needs to go in a new small branch and merge it into dev so I have what we need but, for the future if I stomp on larger changes that would be more complicated than just copy paste I would like to know I can get changes back that can't be gotten by rolling back because we progressed too far from the original branch.

Comment: If I'm getting what you mean, sure - you can look at `git diff` for the merge commit and find the stomped-upon lines -- and cooler still, `git diff -R` to get a reverse diff, i.e. a diff that would unstomp them.

Comment: This is easily done with any decent IDE, opening a file and asking to compare with a previous version.... then copying lines around. It can also be done by hand by diffing and then getting the lines and cleaning the +/- and pasting them in the right location of the file. There are fancier ways, but that is easy enough to carry out.

Comment: Yeah, git diff was how we found the code that got stomped on. By hand copy/paste seems our only option. I was kinda hoping there was some option that would allow me to go back and cherry-pick lines of code that were selected to _**not**_ be merged and bring them forward. BTW for my own edification... @AKX how did you answer my question 3 minutes before I asked it?

Comment: @ObsidianSilence "42 minutes ago" is further away in the past than "39 minutes ago", I'm not a time wizard (yet).

Comment: That is a correct statement. According to my calculations however, "32 minutes ago" is after "35 minutes ago" [Time Travel Proof](https://i.imgur.com/ng0FXS1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio go to git repository and click local history:
[image]

In devops, go to branch history and look at the branch pre-merge.  You can also look at the specific file history in devops.